# error with lubridate formatting when performing conditional assignment with data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table, conditional-statements, lubridate

I have a data.table with a column of dates. I need to create a new column that either adds 1 year or 2 years based on whether the original date is before or after some date.

```
library(data.table); library(lubridate)

name  = c("A", "B", "C")
paid  = c("5/30/2016", "6/30/2016", "7/30/2016")
data  = data.table(name,paid)

new_release = mdy("6/1/2017")

data[, paid := mdy(paid)]

data[, change_date:= ifelse(paid + years(1) < new_release, 
                            paid + years(2), paid +years(1)) ]
```

I get the result below. `lubridate` cannot convert it to a date. I've tried wrapping the `ifelse` statement with `mdy` and this doesn't work either. I know the conditional statement is working, because if you replace the assignments with `TRUE`/`FALSE`, it correctly assigns the values.

```
> data
   name       paid change_date
1:    A 2016-05-30  1527638400
2:    B 2016-06-30  1498780800
3:    C 2016-07-30  1501372800
> str(data)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ name       : chr  "A" "B" "C"
 $ paid       : POSIXct, format: "2016-05-30" "2016-06-30" "2016-07-30"
 $ change_date: num  1.53e+09 1.50e+09 1.50e+09
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Answer (score 3):

I just leave lubdridate out and do it all with basic Date types:

```
library(data.table)

name  <- c("A", "B", "C")
paid  <- as.Date(c("2016-05-30", "2016-06-30", "2016-07-30"))
data  <- data.table(name,paid)

new_release <- as.Date("2017-06-01")
year <- 365.25

data[, change_date:= as.Date(ifelse(paid + year < new_release, 
                                    paid + year*2, 
                                    paid + year)) ]
```

Then:

```
R> data[]
   name       paid change_date
1:    A 2016-05-30  2018-05-30
2:    B 2016-06-30  2017-06-30
3:    C 2016-07-30  2017-07-30
R>
```

But the `ifelse()` feels weird in the context of `data.table`. Here is an alternative:

```
R> data[, cdate := paid+year ]                              # baseline
R> data[paid + year < new_release, cdate := paid + 2*year]  # 
R> data[]
   name       paid change_date      cdate
1:    A 2016-05-30  2018-05-30 2018-05-30
2:    B 2016-06-30  2017-06-30 2017-06-30
3:    C 2016-07-30  2017-07-30 2017-07-30
R>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `ifelse` strips attributes and thus removes the date-formatting (see: `?ifelse`). To get the date-formatting back, you can wrap your `ifelse` statement in `as.Date` with `origin = '1970-01-01'`:

```
data[, change_date := as.Date(ifelse(paid + years(1) < new_release, 
                                     paid + years(2), 
                                     paid + years(1)), 
                              origin = '1970-01-01')]
```

which gives:

```
> data
   name       paid change_date
1:    A 2016-05-30  2018-05-30
2:    B 2016-06-30  2017-06-30
3:    C 2016-07-30  2017-07-30
```

Or correct it afterwards by assigning the class of the `paid` column to the `change_date` column:

```
data[, change_date := ifelse(paid + years(1) < new_release, 
                             paid + years(2), 
                             paid + years(1))]
class(data$change_date) <- class(data$paid)
```

which will give you the same result.

---

An alternative for the `ifelse` which achieves the same (still using `lubridate`):

```
data[, change_date := paid + years(as.numeric((paid + years(1) < new_release) + 1))]
```

giving:

```
> data
   name       paid change_date
1:    A 2016-05-30  2018-05-30
2:    B 2016-06-30  2017-06-30
3:    C 2016-07-30  2017-07-30
```